# How do I change the id of a hidden_field_tag to be unique for each id?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3.2, hidden-field

I am having a bit of a problem with ruby on Rails version 3.2. I just can't get the html to generate correctly. To accomplish this I need some help figuring out how to set the id of a hidden_field_tag correctly so that each id is unique per inventory so that I can use a submit button called Equip me to pass along  the correct value.

The following code below generates an almost exact replica of the radio button html content, except the id field for this one is off by one space.

```
     <%= hidden_field_tag :inventory_id, inventory.id, {:id => ['inventory_id_', inventory.id]} %>
```

This above code will generate this html syntax:

```
<input id="inventory_id_ 5" name="inventory_id" value="5" type="hidden">
```

The radio button code which looks like this.
`<%= radio_button_tag :inventory_id, inventory.id %>`

And generates the following html code:

```
<input id="inventory_id_5" name="inventory_id" value="5" type="radio">
```

My Question is how do I go from this?

```
<input id="inventory_id_ 5" name="inventory_id" value="5" type="hidden">
```

To this, which is what I want to see as part of the html code:

```
<input id="inventory_id_5" name="inventory_id" value="5" type="hidden">
```

By fixing up this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :inventory_id, inventory.id, {:id => ['inventory_id_', inventory.id]} %>
```

I know the syntax of this is not perfect but I need this value to be attached to the id so each inventory I use is unique and different so that I can use this field correctly instead of just seeing 6 for every single other inventory even though the values are different.

Do you know if this is even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would use interpolation:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :inventory_id, inventory.id, {:id => 'inventory_id_'#{inventory.id}} %>
```

Basically, anything in curly braces immediately following a hash will get evaluated as Ruby and inserted into the HTML.